# How to find the sparsest vector in a given subspace of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, algorithms, np-complete, coding-theory

A subspace $C$ of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ is given for some $n \geq 1$.
The space $C$ is given by its basis.

Is there a polynomial time algorithm to find the (nonzero) vector in $C$ of lowest hamming weight?

**Motivation**: Finding the distance of a given linear code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the purposes of this problem, we restrict ourselves to *linear codes* presented in terms of its *generator* (or equivalently, the *parity check*) matrix. Then Alexander Vardy (1997) showed that computing the minimum distance of a linear code exactly is NP-hard. [The decision version of this problem is: given a linear code $C$ and a bound $k$, does there exist a nonzero codeword $c$ in $C$ of weight $k$ or less? This version is NP-complete.]

There have been several improvements to this basic result -- it's now known that it's also quite hard to (a.) approximate the distance, (b.) decode a received word under the promise that there is a unique codeword close to it, etc. Unfortunately, I don't quite have the time right now to detail all the known developments, but this seems to be a good place to start: http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~daniele/Research/CodeComp.html . I will try to expand this answer later.

**Reference:**

A. Vardy, *The Intractability of Computing the Minimum Distance of a Code* - IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, 1997.

Comment: I posted this answer on the OP's request. In the mean time, if someone else has a better, more detailed answer, I request them to post it -- I will delete my answer then.

Comment: Please don't delete the answer unless your reference is _also_ included in said "better, more detailed answer".

Comment: +1. Vardy's result came to mind for me, too. I would need to check (algorithmic complexity is a very weak area for me), but IIRC the NP-hard problem is to decide whether a linear code with a given generator matrix has a word of a weight below a given bound or not.

Comment: @Jyrki, Yes, if my understanding is right, the input is a generator matrix defining a code and the problem is to find the smallest weight of a nonzero word. I am stating it this way because I prefer to think in terms of the optimisation version; you describe the decision version accurately.

Comment: @Jyrki I have stated the result a bit more precisely. Thanks.

Comment: @Srivatsan Thanks for filling us all in, and for fixing my error! For some reason I always confuse the NP-hard and NP-complete versions :-)